# Linear search of a linked list

Tags: java, search, linked-list, linear-search

I am trying to do a linear search of a `linked list`. One search is by `int` and the other `String`. What am I doing wrong? **Updated the code based on recommendations.

Within the main

```
    public static LinkedList<Contributor> contributorList = new LinkedList<>();

        String searchKey = "Jones";
        int intSearchKey = 45;

        System.out.println("Search key " + searchKey + " is found? " + sequentialSearch(contributorList, searchKey));

        System.out.println("Search key " + intSearchKey + " is found? " + sequentialSearch(contributorList, intSearchKey));



Called methods    



    public static <Contributor> boolean sequentialSearch(Iterable<Contributor> contributorList, int intSearchKey) {
    Iterator<Contributor> iter = contributorList.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (iter.next().equals(intSearchKey)) {
            return true;
        }
        iter = (Iterator<Contributor>) iter.next();
    }
    return false;
}

public static <Contributor> boolean sequentialSearch(Iterable<Contributor> contributorList, String searchKey) {
    Iterator<Contributor> iter = contributorList.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (iter.next().equals(searchKey)) {
            return true;
        }
        iter = (Iterator<Contributor>) iter.next();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a linked list in your code.

Comment: what you implement is better described not by `search` word but by `contains` - you method doesn't return `T` item.

Comment: why not use `contributorList.contains(key)` directly?

Comment: An `Iterable` is not a linked list (but a `LinkedList` **is** an `Iterable`). So your question really is about checking containment in an iterable, because the `sequentialSearch` method has nothing to do with the linked list structure. Also, calling an `Iterable` by the name `collection` is going to become quite confusing in even a moderately big code.

Comment: What's the actual problem? You've basically just told us it doesn't work without telling us *how* it doesn't work. Your code is also a little confusing because it seems like you have code that exists outside a method block but probably exists inside one instead (like `sequentialSearch (contributorList, "Jones");`). It's hard to help without seeing the *actual* code you're using.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and is your code even compiling? The first `sequentialSearch` isn't relevant because you don't have an array of `T` anywhere. The second won't match either of the calls because neither a string nor an int value matches when `T` is bound to `Contributor`. Do you mean for 45 to be an index into the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line compares a Contributor object to a String.

```
if (iter.next().equals(searchKey)) {
```

Without seeing Contributor object, I'm guessing you want something like this

```
if (iter.next().getKey().equals(searchKey)) {
```

Also, this line makes no sense:

```
 iter = (Iterator<Contributor>) iter.next();
```

iter.next() returns the element type, not an iterator

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code you have here:

```
Iterator<Contributor> iter = contributorList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().equals(intSearchKey)) {
        return true;
    }
    iter = (Iterator<Contributor>) iter.next();
}
```

Notice that in the first call to `.next()`, you're expecting it to return a `Contributor` object. In the second case, you're expecting it to return something that can be converted to an `Iterator<Contributor>`.

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how iterators work in Java, which is why the code doesn't work. The `.next()` method on an iterator automatically advances the iterator forward - it modifies the receiver - and returns the next value in the collection being iterated over. This means that you shouldn't assign `iter` a new value when calling `.next()`, since you'd have incompatible types. Rather, you should probably structure the code like this:

```
Iterator<Contributor> iter = contributorList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Contributor currElem = iter.next();
    if (currElem.equals(intSearchKey)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Notice that you call `.next()` just once in the loop to get the value, then use that value on the current loop iteration. You never reassign `iter`, since `iter` automatically walks through the collection as you repeatedly call `.next()`.

Hope this helps!